# Broken NOR gate

Tags: transistors, digital-logic

[image]
<sub>(source: [electronics-tutorials.ws](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/log46.gif))</sub>

I recently constructed a NOR gate using the following schematic
but when one of the transistors is set to HIGH an led I connected to the output of the gate glows brighter, but the other one works just fine. What's causing this?

Comment: First, why do you think this circuit implements a NOR gate? It looks like AND to me. Second, how was the LED connected? From the output to +6V or from the output to ground?

Comment: Sorry, wrong schematic, fixed it and the LED was connected at OUT to the ground of an arduino which supplied the power for the gate

Comment: The question is not clear to me.  You connected an LED to the `OUT` terminal of the gate, and when one of the inputs (let's say `A`) is HIGH (*so from the truth table, OUT should be LOW*), the LED glows brighter, and the other one works just fine?  What is the 'other one', and what would 'fine' behaviour be for you?

Comment: On one of the transistors if i set it to HIGH it behaves as it should, the LED turns off, but on the other one the LED glows brighter when it's set to HIGH

Comment: You've got a NAND gate schematic up there now.

Comment: @Samuel, looks like NOR to me. The two transistors' c-e paths are in parallel, not series --- though it might be hard to see if you're looking at it on your phone or something.

Comment: @kaptainkernel, nothing in the schematic explains the behavior you're describing. Can you post a photo of the physical circuit?

Comment: @ThePhoton Ah, you're right.

Comment: Simple test, if you put two LEDs in series does it still function improperly, what about if you increase R2?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a NOR gate now, albeit non-standard RTL input levels.  TTL is two diode drops and HCMOS is Vcc/2 threshold.
The saturated gain of a transistor is only 10 to 20.  So choose R values for a gain of 10 for reliable current switching.

CMOS NOR Gate

This is a [simplified CMOS NOR gate](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/#%24+0+5.0E-6+9.78399845368213+50+5.0+50%0Af+304+112+368+112+5+1.5%0Aw+368+128+368+160+0%0AR+368+96+368+48+0+0+40.0+5.0+0.0+0.0+0.5%0Af+304+176+368+176+5+1.5%0Aw+368+192+368+208+0%0Aw+368+208+368+224+0%0Af+304+240+368+240+4+1.5%0AM+368+208+432+208+0+2.5%0Af+208+240+272+240+4+1.5%0Aw+272+208+272+224+0%0Aw+272+208+368+208+0%0Ag+272+256+272+288+0%0Ag+368+256+368+288+0%0Aw+304+176+304+240+0%0Aw+208+112+208+240+0%0Aw+208+112+304+112+0%0AR+112+112+64+112+1+3+100.0+2.5+2.5+0.0+0.5%0AR+112+176+64+176+1+3+110.0+2.5+2.5+0.0+0.5%0Aw+304+176+160+176+0%0Aw+208+112+160+112+0%0Aw+160+112+112+112+0%0Aw+160+176+112+176+0%0Ar+416+208+480+208+0+220.0%0A162+480+208+480+256+1+2.1024259+1.0+0.0+0.0%0Ag+480+256+480+288+0%0Aw+368+208+416+208+0%0Ao+20+64+0+35+8.183476519740355+4.8828125000000005E-155+0+-1%0Ao+17+64+0+35+9.353610478917778+9.765625E-55+0+-1%0Ao+7+64+0+290+10.0+9.765625E-5+0+-1%0A) with fancy triangular inputs running at 100 & 110 Hz to give a 10 Hz beat frequency on the output. Purpose is to show the linear input threshold.  This uses n and p Mosfets to give low impedance for both output states, although the high side usually has a resistor to current limit it.